# How to save pandas series in a single row instead of column

Tags: python, pandas

By default pandas series is stored in a single column when we do

```
series.to_csv('series.csv')
```

but I want to store it in a single row like I want to store transpose of it.
I tried

```
series.T.to_csv('series.csv')
```

but still output in csv is in a single column and in multiple rows, but I need in single rows and multiple columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try via `to_frame()`:

```
series.to_frame().T.to_csv('series.csv',index=False)
#If you don't want to include header then pass header=False in the to_csv() method
```